# Conditional Assignment of Fields

Tags: c#

I have an issue where I am loading in data from an xml file and saving that into my domain model objects.  The issue is the xml file is not consistent in that not all records with contain the same attributes.

For example in the code below the variable roundingRule may not always exist.  Can I somehow put a conditional statement around this field so that it will be skipped if there is nothing to assign.

```
var workRule = new WorkRule
{
    Name = (string) element.Attribute("Name"),
    CustomerId = 11,
    PunchRoundRuleId = roundingRule,
    EffectiveDate = effectiveDate,
    ExceptionRuleId = exceptionRule,
    PayCodeDistributionName = payCodeDistributionName,
    DayDivideOverride = dayDivideOverride,
    UnapprovedOvertimePayCodeName = unapprovedOvertimePayCodeName,
    ExceptionRuleName = exceptionRuleName,
};
```

Comment: You can't skip, but you can assign alternate value using conditional operator. If at all you want to skip why stick to object initializer syntax? You can always use property syntax.

Comment: if there is nothing, then why you worry? just leave the nothing(null) assigned to the property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do something like this:

```
var workRule = new
{
    Name = element.Attribute("Name") == null
        ? "N/A"
        : (string)element.Attribute("Name"),
};
```

Comment: Thanks - That will not really work for me as the fields I want to skip are the Foreign Key Fields i.e. Punch Round Rule ID.  However you have given me another idea that will work and that is after the assignment of the value I just put a line to check if the id field is == zero and if it is I set it to null.  This solves my problem